# HTML - How do I make text vertical middle in <p>

Tags: html, css

I want my text to be vertically middle in `<p>` instead of align to the bottom.

My code:

```
<p style="color:red;text-align:left;">
  <img src="https://i.ibb.co/zFNxsT4/1.png" width="25"> &nbsp;&nbsp;
  <b>Where Should I go ? </b>
</p>
```

And the result:

[image]

i have tried `vertical-align:middle` but it doesn't have any changes.
Any other ways that it could make the text vertically align in middle?

Comment: vertical-align:middle applied to the image.

Comment: @fcalderan thanks! probably the most accurate answer to solve my issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set `vertical-align: middle` on the children of your `<p>` element:

```css
p {
  color: red;
  text-align: left;
}

img { 
  width: 25px;
}

p > * {
  vertical-align: middle;
}
```

```html
<p>
  <img src="https://i.ibb.co/zFNxsT4/1.png"> &nbsp;&nbsp;
  <b>Where Should I go ?</b>
</p>
```

Comment: That won't center the `b` element.

Answer (score 1):

The only (and the best cross-browser) way as I know is to use an `inline-block` helper with `height: 100%` and `vertical-align: middle` on elements.

Answer (score 1):

I would use `flexbox`

I changed your markup a little bit, hope it's alright. It uses `<strong>` instead of `<b>` and I gave the image a `height` aswell.

```css
.flex {
  display: flex;
}

.flex strong {
  align-self: center;
}
```

```html
<p class="flex">
  <img src="https://i.ibb.co/zFNxsT4/1.png" width="25" height="25"> &nbsp;&nbsp;
  <strong>Where Should I go ? </strong>
</p>
```

[**Fiddle demo**](https://jsfiddle.net/jafz254m/)

Answer (score 1):

You could use flexbox to do this. Also, it would be semantically more correct to write your code like this:

```css
.wrapper {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  flex-wrap: nowrap;
}

.image {
  flex: 0 0 auto;
  width: 25px;
  margin: 0 10px 0 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <img class="image" src="https://i.ibb.co/zFNxsT4/1.png">
  <p style="color:red;">Where Should I go ? </p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

There is absolutly no need for tables or any other stuff.

You may use `vertical-align: middle`.
But you need to set the images `vertical-align` aswell. Otherwise a `vertical-align` is not specified.

Here is a working version:

HTML

```
<p style="color:red; text-align:left;">
  <img src="https://i.ibb.co/zFNxsT4/1.png" width="25">
  <b>Where Should I go ? </b>
</p>
```

CSS

```
p > img, p > b {
    vertical-align: middle;
}
```

FIDDLE
https://jsfiddle.net/e2y1cL07/

*Pro tip:*

*If I want to row elements side-by-side and automatically want them to move to the parents `width`, I apply `display: inline-block` to each children of my parent.*

Answer (score 0):

Try to add flex to your p it will set content inside in the middle:

```
display: flex;
align-items: center;
```